# A problem with UNION Query Usage 

Tags: mysql

The issue here is suppose if i want to use two queries seperated by UNION, the query is as

```
             $query=(select a.name,a.age,b.country,b.state from a,b where a.aid=b.bid)  UNION (select a.name,a.age,c.profession,c.salary from a,c where a.anid=c.cid)
```

here the result would only show the first query's result , Any way in which i could display the result of 2nd query also down to the result of first query using UNION. Expecting any help on this. Thanks

Comment: It's not at all clear what type of result you're hoping to get

Comment: dont simply down vote, there are others who are following the discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after

```
(
  select a.name,a.age,b.country,b.state,null as profession,null as salary 
  from a,b
  where a.aid=b.bid
)  
UNION 
(
   select a.name,a.age,null,null,c.profession,c.salary
   from a,c
   where a.anid=c.cid
)
```

You will have null in the profession and salary columns from the first query and null in country and state columns in the second query

Comment: I need to use it like this since , the result of the sql must be written into a csv file.@ bob vale

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query=(select a.name,a.age,b.country,b.state from a,b where a.aid=b.bid UNION select a.name,a.age,c.profession,c.salary from a,c where a.anid=c.cid)
```

by the way the fields in both select must be the same datatype

Comment: but the answer seems to be same as what i had posted

Comment: Its no the same, chick it out

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it a union was to do the same query on two different tables.  If you get a result from the first half of the union you will not get the results from the second half.

Answer (score 0):

Basic property of `UNION` is

> Selected columns listed in
>   corresponding positions of each SELECT
>   statement should have the same data
>   type. (For example, the first column
>   selected by the first statement should
>   have the same type as the first column
>   selected by the other statements.)
>
> If the data types of corresponding
>   SELECT columns do not match, the types
>   and lengths of the columns in the
>   UNION result take into account the
>   values retrieved by all of the SELECT
>   statements. For example, consider the
>   following:

Comment: u mean if the first query has integer data type for the field then correspondingly the second query should also have integer datatyoe for field, or both should have same name for fields

Comment: both query's select item's `datatype` should be integer